# Azure Service Fabric Existing Data MIgration

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I want to migrate an existing Web Application that connects to SQL Server into a Service Fabric solution. My application already has hundreds of thousands of rows of data in multiple tables. I want to create the application from the beginning and use Stateful Services in Service Fabric. How do I transfer all my existing data into the Reliable Collections that the Stateful Services will use?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to think about a way to [partition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-concepts-partitioning) your existing data first, so you can [divide](https://youtu.be/fN9zQm_FVVw) it across multiple Stateful service replicas.

Next, you must deploy the application and pass the data to the right service service replica. For example, you can create an [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-aspnetcore) for this, or use [Remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-connect-and-communicate-with-services) calls from within the cluster.

Also think of a [backup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-backup-restore) strategy to deal with cluster failures and human error. Store your backup data away from the cluster.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I do understand the first point you made. For the second point about passing the data to the proper service replica, in what format do I pass the data? My data is in SQL Server. Do I export the data in csv or json? There is no information about this anywhere I look.

Comment: SF stores its data by storing (serialized) immutable objects. Suppose you have customers and orders. For example, you can decide to store Customer objects and Order objects, or complete object graphs combining Customers and Orders inside different reliable collections.  More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-reliable-collections-guidelines

Comment: You need to translate your relational data into object graph data. The graph shape is largely determined by the way you search for the data, which is most efficient by key.

Comment: You can also simply keep using SQL server from SF the way you are doing it now.

Comment: So there is no easy way to migrate the data. I would have to somehow restructure into objects and programmatically transfer the data into the collections. That is not a very good solution in my opinion for moving existing data into SF. Regarding keep using SQL, this means I cannot use stateful services correct?

Comment: You can still use them, but it's likely that you don't need them.